# Remote debugging of R code?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

Is there a way to connect R Studio to remote instance of R and do debugging? Would R Studio server help in this?

Essentially I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu Linux with R setup on it and would like to be able to perform debugging from the host machine.

Comment: Yes and yes ...

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit or at least pass some link outlining the process?

Comment: Install RStudio Server. Then use it like RStudio. Simple, really.